# how to update the textfield value in ios

Tags: iphone, ios, ios5, uitextfield

I have one textfield value like 100,000 using NSNumberFormatter, now I want to edit my textfield, to add one more 0 . After I Want to Change like the text like 1,000,000 but my textfield value is changed as 0

Comment: @Kai thank you for your reply, how i get the value pls help me

Comment: I just can't ... I don't have the slightest idea what exactly you're trying. That's why I asked about how questions like these get upvoted.

Comment: Why on earth was that edit approved? It actually makes it worse...

Comment: @GrahamBorland please edit my question, for getting the answer. thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
numberFormatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
[numberFormatter setNumberStyle: NSNumberFormatterNoStyle];
[numberFormatter setGroupingSize:3];
[numberFormatter setGroupingSeparator:@","];
[numberFormatter setUsesGroupingSeparator:YES];
number= [NSNumber numberWithInt:[textFieldString intValue]];
NSString *numberString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"$%@",[numberFormatter stringForObjectValue:number]];
```

try this

Answer (score 0):

try like this,

```
 int x=[textfield.text intValue];
```

you can get the correct value.....

Comment: thank you for your reply, i will check it and then i will told you

Answer (score 0):

Try this code. It may help you

```
  NSNumberFormatter *numberFormatter = [[[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init] autorelease];
    [numberFormatter setFormat:@"#,###"];
    NSNumber *averageResponseTime = [NSNumber numberWithInt:[textfield.text intValue]];

//If you print text 


 [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%@ms",[numberFormatter stringForObjectValue:averageResponseTime]];
```

Comment: thank you for your reply, i will check and then told to you

Comment: @kai notworked at the fourth line of code i got an error @\

Comment: Replace the [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%d",[numberFormatter stringForObjectValue:averageResponseTime]];