# NSString To NSNumber with format

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, nsstring, nsnumber

I have a StopWatch in my app. The time is displayed on a label with format: mm:ss.SSS as an NSString. I need to convert it to NSNumber. I searched Google many times, but couldn't find the answer.

Thanks!

Comment: What do you want the NSNumber to represent? Seconds, milliseconds, days?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12263832/how-to-update-the-textfield-value-in-ios/12264211#12264211

look this link maybe helpful for you

Comment: i need it as a float value that i can equal it to another score later.. e.g: if (stopwatch.text < 5.673) then... etc

Answer (score 1):

The following gives you the date/time as a number in seconds since the reference date.

```
NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[formatter setDateFormat:@"mm:ss"];
NSDate *date = [formatter dateFromString:textField.text];
NSNumber *dateAsNumber = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:[date timeIntervalSince1970]];
```

Answer (score 0):

try the code below :

```
NSNumberFormatter * f = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
[f setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterDecimalStyle];
NSNumber * myNumber = [f numberFromString:@"42"];
[f release];
```

but change @"42" with your label_name.text

Answer (score 0):

This is the way you can convert an NSString into NSNumber.

```
NSString *timeFormat = @"Your Time";
NSNumber *time = [NSNumber numberWithInt:[timeFormat integerValue]];
```

Comment: It's the correct way to convert NSString into NSNumber.... Either you are going to implement wrong logic or anything else, then I don't know, but it's correct, I used it.